# The visited link does not work how to fix it

Tags: html

The HTML appears to be in order but I cannot seem to find where my error is. I am not capable of making my links appear to be visited.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mornington Peninsula</title>
    
    <!--Link to stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <!--Header Section In which the logo is placed-->
            <header>
                <div class="headingpic"> 
                    <img src="sorrento_by_the_sea_logo.jpg" alt="Sorrent by The Sea Logo">
                </div>
            </header>
            <!--Navigation section-->
            <nav>
                <ul class="navigator">
                    <li ><a href="INDEX.html">HOME</a></li>
                    
                    <li class="navigation"><a href="CONTACT.html">CONTACT & DIRECTIONS</a></li>
                
                    <li><a href="SEE&DO&EAT.html">SEE/DO & EAT</a></li>
                
                    <li><a href="ACCOMMODATION.html">ACCOMMODATION</a></li>  
                </ul>   
            </nav>
            
            <!--Contact Info: MOBILE-->
                <h2>Sorrento by the Sea Apartment - Luxury Self Contained Apartment </h2>
                    <section class="contact">
                        
                        <div class="flexycontainer3">  
                            <div>
                                <h3>Contact Details</h3>
                            </div> 
                            <div>
                                <a class="button" href="mailto:wealthyness@wealthyness.com">Email: wealthyness@wealthyness.com</a>        
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <a class="button" href="tel:0435-123-456">PHONE: 0435-123-456</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section> 
                
                
                <!--Directions to Destination-->
                <h2>Getting here</h2>
                    <section>
                    <div class="flexycontainer">    
                        <div>    
                            <h3>Via Ferry</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>If you choose to come across on the Queenscliff/Sorrento Ferry, it is only a 2 minute drive from the Ferry Depot.</p>
                            <h4>OR</h4>
                            <p>If you are a foot passenger we are happy to meet you at the Sorrento ferry at. Just phone us on <a class="phonelink" href="tel:0435-123-456">PHONE: 0435-123-456</a> as you arrive.</p>
                            <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/42+Holyrood+Ave,+Sorrento+VIC+3943/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x6ad4357b0e516369:0xf1dce538da37e359?sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwitj9eTs7nqAhVY4jgGHenmA-gQ8gEwAHoECAsQAQ"><img src="Sorrento.png" alt="Sorrento Location" class="image"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>        
                    <div class="flexycontainer">
                        <div>       
                            <h3>Scenic Land Route</h3>
                        </div>    
                        <div>    
                            <p>It is easy to find. From Melbourne, take the Monash Freeway, connect onto the Eastlink heading for Portsea, then onto the Peninsula link to Sorrento.</p>
                            <p>Another option is the scenic drive around the beach. Although longer, it allows you to experience the coastline from Port Melbourne to Sorrento. </p>
                            <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/42+Holyrood+Ave,+Sorrento+VIC+3943/@-38.3477012,144.7463679,16.36z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x6ad4357b0e516369:0xf1dce538da37e359!8m2!3d-38.3474225!4d144.7498093"><img src="Map_sorrent.png" alt="Directions To Sorrento By the See" class="image"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    </section>

                <!--The link to social Medias conerning Mornington Peninsula-->
                <footer>
                        <!--Photo Links for Social Medias due to them being widely known by their app icons-->
                        <ul class="contact-list">
                            <li class="linkimg"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/morningtonpeninsula"><img src="facebook_small.png" alt="Facebook Link">Facebook</a></li>

                            <li class="linkimg"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/mornigntonpeninsula/" target="_blank"><img src="instagram_small.png" alt="Instagram Link">Instagram</a></li>
                            
                            <li class="linkimg"><a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23mornington%20penisula&src=typed_query" target="_blank"><img src="twitter_small.png" alt="Twitter Link">Twitter</a></li>
                            
                            <li class="linkimg"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=mornington+peninsula" target="_blank"><img src="youtube-variation_small.png" alt="Youtube Link">YouTube</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </footer>
        </main>

    </body>
</html>
```

There seems to be an issue with my CSS and I do not know where I have gone wrong my visited link is not working. I think it is a issue with how I have layed out my classes they are messy.

CSS Code

```
/*Global Sizings*/
html
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*Website Logo/Heading*/
/*-------------------------*/
header 
{
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(104, 39, 33); width: 100%;  
}

.headingpic
{
    background-image: image("sorrento_by_the_sea_logo.jpg");
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: auto;
}

body
{
    color: #343434;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Calibri', 'Times New Roman';
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background-color: #B8860B;
 }

h3
{
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #4d1d18;
}

.heading3
{
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
   background-position: center;
   background-color: rgb(255,255,240);
   margin-left: 0.265cm;
   margin-right: 0.265cm;
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   border-bottom: solid;
   font-size: 24px;
   border-radius: 1px;
   border-color: steelblue;
   color: #4d1d18;
}

h2
{
   text-align: center;
   background-position: center;
   background-color: rgb(255,255,240);
   margin-left: 0.265cm;
   margin-right: 0.265cm;
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   border-bottom: solid;
   font-size: 36px;
   border-radius: 1px;
   border-color: steelblue;
  color: #87423c;
}


.image
{
  width: 550px;
  height: 300px;
  image-resolution: optimizequality;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
}

p
{
  line-height: 150%;
  font-size: 20px;
}

div
{
  column-gap: 20px;
}

/*Navigation Section*/
/*--------------------------*/
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.navigator .navigation
{
  background-color: blue;
}


/*Flex formatting*/
/*-------------------------*/
.flexycontainer
{
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  column-gap: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  
  /*
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-top: solid;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border-color: steelblue;
  */
}

.flexycontainer
{
  background-color: #FAF0E6; 
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px; 
}


.flexycontainer1
{
  background-color: none; 
  margin: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}

.flexycontainer1
{
  background-color: #FAF0E6; 
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.flexycontainer2
{
  background-color: none; 
  margin: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}

.flexycontainer2
{
  background-color: #FAF0E6; 
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.flexycontainer3
{
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: auto;
  column-gap: 20px;
}

.flexycontainer3
{
  background-color: #FAF0E6; 
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

/*Div Styling*/
/*-------------------------*/

.divi1
{
  width: 15cm;
  margin-right: 0%;
}

.termsdiv
{
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 150%;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               px;
}


/*Contact Info Stylings*/
.contact
{
  background-color: none;
}

.contact a
{
  color: none;
}

.contact .button
{
  color:#87423c;
  background: skyblue; 
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;

}

.contact .button:hover {
  background: grey;
}
.contact .button:active
{
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
}
.contact .button:visited
{
  background-color: black;
}
.button
{
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/*Footer formatting*/
footer
{
    color: #F7FFF7;
    text-align: center; 
    height: 80px;   
}

.contact-list
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    column-gap: 60px;
}

  .contact-list a
{
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #87423c;
}

/*Links*/
.contact-list:active
{
  color: blue;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.phonelink
{
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active
{
  color: white;
}

.contact-list a:visited
{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you are observing?

Comment: My links are not changing colour after being clicked

Comment: which ones in the footer?

Answer (score -1):

**css tools -**

`a { color:green; }` this is to define the style for link in normal time

`a :hover{ color:blue; }` - it is work when the mouse is hover over on the link

`a :focus{ color:black; }` - when you are clicking on this link change the color to black

Answer (score -4):

You are doing in wrong way! You have to place these links in head section of html with link tag. Same link tag You use for style sheet.